# Trouble with fixing a picture in CV Template next to Header

Tags: horizontal-alignment, header-footer, align, includegraphics

I am writing a professiontal CV using https://github.com/deedy/Deedy-Resume
template and to provide a photo next to the header what modifications do I need to make ?

Comment: I have added the github link : https://github.com/deedy/Deedy-Resume
Overleaf link : https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/deedy-cv/bjryvfsjdyxz#.U2H9Kq1dV18

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start your document as

```
% !TeX TS-program = xelatex

\documentclass[]{deedy-resume-openfont}

%********************************************* 
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancyhf{} % clear header and footer
\pagestyle{fancy} % choose the style
\usepackage{graphicx}% added <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}% suppress line after header
\fancyhead[LO]{\includegraphics[height=3.5cm,keepaspectratio, trim=-0 0 0 -7cm]{example-image}}% insert your photo <<<<
%********************************************* 
 
\begin{document}

\lastupdated
.....
```

Using the template you will get

[image: a]

or use

```
\fancyhead[RO]{\includegraphics[height=3.5cm,keepaspectratio, trim=-0 0 0 -7cm]{example-image}}%
```

to have the photo on the right of the page:

[image: b]

**Important**  Use the parameter `trim=left bottom right top` to adjust the position of the image.

The example uses `trim=-0 0 0 -7cm` but the correct amount of scrolling down will depend on the size of the image.